# Compacting node_modules for client-side deployment

Tags: node.js, npm, gruntjs, browserify

I'm implementing a client-side application in JavaScript using Node.js. Because I will be deploying the software on many machines, I would like to minimize the size of the package I distribute. In particular, I would like to remove any unnecessary files from node_modules.

For starters this means deduping and pruning the dependency tree, which `npm` can do for me. But I'd also like to remove all the `package.json` files and (especially) any other files that are not needed for deployment. In many of the packages I am using there are tons of tests, multiple versions of files (minified, browserified, etc.) and the like. I just need the JavaScript files that are actually used by the running app. Otherwise I'll be distributing a few 100Kb of files that aren't actually used.

I know about [`node-browserify`](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify) but my app will be running in a CommonJS environment, not a browser, so I'd like to keep the modules separate and load them with `require`.

I'm thinking about writing a Grunt plugin that walks the dependency tree using [`required`](https://github.com/shtylman/node-required), pulls out the JavaScript files needed at runtime and writes them to a tree structure so they can be loaded using `require` (just loading the modules directly without needing a `package.json`). But I'd like to make sure no one has done this for me before I tackle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW: [`grunt-package-minifier`](https://github.com/salsita/grunt-package-minifier). My use case is a bit unusual since we are developing a [cross-browser extension framework](http://www.ancho.io). Like [`Browserify`](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify) and unlike standard NodeJS deployments we want to minimize the size of our distribution, including any CommonJS modules. But unlike `Browserify` we support CommonJS so we can keep the module structure rather than concatenating everything into one big file.

Essentially I strip all the `package.json`, README, test files, etc. from `node_modules` but keep the essential JavaScript files in a structure that can be used by a CommonJS module loader.

Answer (score 2):

grun-package-minifier is not found ( This is not an actual answer. I wanted to commet in above answer but I do not have sufficient reputation yet :( ).

npm install grunt-package-minifier --save-dev
Password:
npm WARN package.json zigbee_gateway_js@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json zigbee_gateway_js@0.0.0 No README data
npm ERR! 404 404 Not Found: grunt-package-minifier
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 'grunt-package-minifier' is not in the npm registry.

Comment: I probably didn't add it to NPM but it's available from Github via the link in my answer.